# How to serve a Django project so that many incoming GET requests are handled in parallel

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with some view `my_view`.

My view runs sequentially, but may take a few seconds to complete.

I would like to be able to send several GET requests to this view at the same time and have them processed in parallel.

Currently, they just run sequentially.

How do I achieve this?

`my_view` does not have to be asynchronous.

The docker file looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Stop using runserver, and instead move to something like gunicorn (easy) or uwsgi (less easy but not that bad). runserver is just meant as a way to get developing quickly, you shouldn't use it for anything serious.

Comment: `runserver` is for dev only. For prod - have a look at any of those articles/tutorials like _"running django on prod with nginx and gunicorn"_.

Comment: @IvanStarostin and that will do what I?

Comment: What did you mean by `My view runs sequentially, but may take a few seconds to complete.`?

Comment: @ruddra `my_view` doesnt do any multi-threading or spawn any processes itself. It is self contained. However the request "GET `host:port/my_view` takes a few seconds because of what `my_view` is doing before returning a response

Answer (score 1):

**STOP using `runserver` for anything but local development!** This command is intended only for local development and no safety nor concurrency is guaranteed with it.

For your answer, to handle those queries properly you have several options:

## Use WSGI server with a high enough number of workers

If this view won't be ever called more than `X` times per time of it's execution, you can set your workers number to anything higher than `X` (depending on your needs) to always ensure accessibility of your application.

## Use any sort of task queue to offload long running task

By offloading your task to for example [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), you can free up worker immediately. Just make sure NOT TO wait for task execution in one request but to provide some way of checking periodically status of your task.

## Use asynchronous code (with help of django-channels) for your long-running task

If you have a lot of IO in this view, you can make it asynchronous, so workers can do other things when waiting for IO to be ready.